# Permission denied using Firebase database with Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

My team is trying to use Firebase Realtime Database in a Flutter app. They changed the `pubspec.yaml` and both `build.gradle` files, and linked `the google-services.json` file as seen in online tutorials. However the tutorials seemed contradictory (between them and even with the documentation).

Here is the relevant part of their code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class ProgramPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProgramPageState createState() => new _ProgramPageState();
}

class _ProgramPageState extends State<ProgramPage> {
  List<Conference> _conferences = List();
  DatabaseReference itemRef;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  static Future<FirebaseApp> _getApp() async {
    const FirebaseOptions myOptions = const FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: '<id>',
      apiKey: '<key>',
      databaseURL: '<url>',
    );
    FirebaseApp app;
    app = await FirebaseApp.configure(name: "conferences", options: myOptions);
    return app;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getApp().then((app) {
      final FirebaseDatabase database = new FirebaseDatabase(app: app);
      itemRef = database.reference().child('conferences');
      itemRef.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
      itemRef.onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChanged);
    });
  }

  _onEntryAdded(Event event) {
    setState(() {
      _conferences.add(Conference.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
  }

  _onEntryChanged(Event event) {
    var old = _conferences.singleWhere((entry) {
      return entry.id == event.snapshot.key;
    });
    setState(() {
      _conferences[_conferences.indexOf(old)] =
          Conference.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    });
  }

  // the build method basically returns a ListView of Conference objects
}
```

But when they run it on an Android emulator, they get these errors :

```
W/SyncTree( 7764): Listen at /conferences failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
E/flutter ( 7764): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7764): Instance of 'DatabaseError'
E/flutter ( 7764): #0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1114:29)
E/flutter ( 7764): #1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 7764): #2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter ( 7764): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7764): Instance of 'DatabaseError'
E/flutter ( 7764): #0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1114:29)
E/flutter ( 7764): #1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 7764): #2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

Could you explain us what is wrong ?

EDIT : Security rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2 : We're using Santosh Anand's solution to simplify rules (security is not a big concern in this project). Now we get these messages :

```
W/zygote  (14174): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (14174): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule(14174): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
I/DynamiteModule(14174): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
W/zygote  (14174): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (14174): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(14174): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/zygote  (14174): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
I/zygote  (14174): After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
I/zygote  (14174): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

Comment: Please include your firebase security rules and structure.

Comment: I the Firebase console where you can view and edit the persisted data. In the "Rules" tab there is a simulator. Add the user id, data to write (if any) and the path you try to access. You'll get a hint what rule causes the permission denied error.

Comment: @AndréKool I'm sorry, I'm not sure what is the structure you're referring to ?

Comment: Looks like you are not authenticated to Firebase. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I think the team is quite lost. We'll try to use this plugin to authenticate, I'll come back with news.

Answer (score 13):

You have to authenticate your application with firebase.

Or

you can make change into security rule like

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post with the new messages we get using your solution.

Comment: You should be aware that with such a configuration everybody can write, delete, or change data in your Firebase database and you'll have to pay the Firebase quota for that.

Answer (score 5):

The following steps solved the problem for me:

**1-enable test mode when creating a real-time database.**

**2- make default database is the real-time database.**

**3- change the rule as following in database tab**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

4- enable anonymous login from the authentication tab.

after that, it does not fix until I used "flutter clean" option

*-> in android studio:  go to tools->Flutter->flutter clean*

Answer (score 2):

1st Question : You are accessing Firebase before authentication , keeping read and write as true works but your authentication becomes useless with respect to security.
2nd Question : That is Firebase Plugin warning they are updating their plugins make sure you are at the lastest version

Answer (score 1):

You have to log in Firebase using the [firebase_auth package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth)

```
void anonymousLogin() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) async {
      if (user != null) {
        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
        var uid = user.uid;
        print(
            'In FirestoreServices, isAnonymous = $isAnonymous and uid = $uid');
      } else {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously().then((user) {
          print(
              'In FirestoreServices, isAnonymous = ${user.isAnonymous} and uid = ${user.uid}');
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Use that function in your main widget to anonymously login to firebase. Make sure that anonymously login is enabled in your firebase console.

Comment: Thanks. For simplicity's sake we are using the other solution, but your code is useful too.

Comment: you'll still have to login anyways. :) 
i find the anonymously login useful to quick start developing the main features instead of being stuck at creating another login page. lol

Comment: Thanks :) They have changed the API a little bit, so now it is `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges` instead of `onAuthStateChanged`. The rest is the same. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate your application with firebase before read or write.

This is the flutter plugin for auth : firebase_auth: ^0.16.1

```
  await FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app).signInAnonymously().then((AuthResult val) {
    print("USER ID. : " + val.user.uid);
  });
```

Your rules are correct for anonymous auth.

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".write": "auth.uid!==null",
        ".read": "auth.uid!==null"
      }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

i am create DatabaseReference object by this code

`itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('conferences');`

and run with me.