# was working well but FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been working on the Flutter app with firebase and the app was working well but today when I trying to retrieve the data from using snapshot I got this exception.

> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

is there any update on firebase i have to do or what ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied using Firebase database with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924437/permission-denied-using-firebase-database-with-flutter)

Comment: where i can edit the security rule ??? with this code 
{
   
 “rules”: {

    “.read”: true,
    “.write”: true
 }

}

Answer (score 1):

When you create a project and set Firestore access it test mode, it sets the database up to allow public access for only a month. If this suddenly happened without a change on your side, it could be that your security rules expired.

Now would be a good moment to implement proper security rules for your data, as leaving all data publicly accessible is a recipe for future problems.

So learn how to secure the data, have a look at the documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started), this more [technical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), and also see:

- [Firestore Permission Denied in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733941/firestore-permission-denied-in-android)
- [Email: [Firebase] Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in X day(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869759/email-firebase-client-access-to-your-cloud-firestore-database-expiring-in-x-d)